# Free bookings within some time window

Tags: mysql, period

In my db bookings are periods with SSTART and SEND fields as period start and end dates. How to find free periods from booking table but free periods within some time window - free booking periods from e.g. '2012-07-01' til '2012-07-31'. On site http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/queries.php#577 one can find how to find free periods but I don't know how to define time window.

Comment: It's generally easier to do this in one's application code: query to obtain booked periods during the desired range and then infer that any date not in the resultset is free.  If you *must* do this within SQL, you would need to construct a table of all dates in which you're interested and outer join against that: this can be done with a `UNION` subquery or with a dedicated (temporary?) table